# Understanding linear algebra notation

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove the following if it is true. Let A be an $m × n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $i \in \{1, . . . , n\}$ be a fixed index. 
(i) There exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $Ax = 0$, $x_j \ge 0 $  for all $j \in\{1, . . . , n\}$, and $x_i \gt  0$

I just have some questions regarding notation. Does $m × n$ strictly mean $m \neq n$ or can it encompass a case when $m = n$ ?

Also what does $x_j$ and $x_i$ mean in this context? I thought it referred to the jth column entry of the matrix and the ith column entry but this would not work as it leads to a contradiction or redundancy.

Comment: After a while most people start to omit the "Let $m,n$ be natural numbers, and ..." from the beginning of such sentences. Unless otherwise stated they are arbitrary natural numbers.

Answer (score 2):

1) This is in full generality. $m=n$ is not ruled out.

2) $x$ is a vector (your problem says it's a real number, but I think that's a typo). $x_i$ and $x_j$ usually refers to the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ entry in that vector respectively. It's a somewhat weird way to write it. I would have written "$x$ contains non-negative entries and $x_i\neq 0$"

Comment: I think it may mean every entry in the vector is real? Not sure.

Comment: @user430765 that would be correctly denoted $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I have edited my answer because I slightly misread the problem, so make sure to reread it.

Comment: And since x is a vector does that mean it's matrix is a single column?

Comment: @user430765 no, you can multiply a matrix by a vector so long as the vector has the same number of elements as the matrix has rows

Comment: Sorry my confusion lies mainly in the $x_i$ and $x_j$ notation. A matrix is normally denoted by row and column, but this notation seems to only single one out. If you describe something by being in the ith row you are not singling any entry out.

Comment: @user430765  $x$ is a vector, not a matrix.